# Excel: How to Sum a Matrix with a Criteria?

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to sum a matrix based off of a criteria of another matrix equaling a criteria.

For example, in matrix 1 there are rows and columns both being dates. The vertical are dates when something "began" and the horizontal is when something "ended."

Matrix 2 takes the ending date and subtracts the starting date to get the amount of days in-between and divides by 30 to get the months before something ended.
My range is up to 120 months and basically I need to sum all of the matrix 1 contents IF the corresponding matrix 2 is equal to the number of months.

In the "months" column I want the sum of matrix 1 numbers IF the months column equals the matrix 2 number

[image]

I tried a few sumifs and sumproducts but can't seem to make it work, I only receive a return of 0

NOTE: The fourth column of matrix 2 is cut off so please imagine there's another column. Finally the intended output is a row to the right of the months column sums matrix 1 for whatever number is associated in matrix 2, so for month 91, there is a cell to the right that sums 3 and 5 (matrix 1 column of 1/1/22 and row of 7/1/14 as well as column 2/1/22 and row 8/1/14).

The formula was simple but the issue was that in matrix 2 the numbers weren't rounded so if I took the actual "month" number without rounding, it wouldn't match anything in the months column

Comment: Please share what's your expected output with data.

Comment: My expected output is a column to the right of the "months" column in the photo that sums matrix 1 numbers IF the number in the months column matches the number in matrix 2. So month 91, for example, would sum all the numbers in matrix one that are associated with 91, which would be 3+5 (the two numbers are the cross of column 2/1/22 and row 8/1/14 as well as the cross of column 1/1/22 and 7/1/14. The fourth column of matrix 2 is cut off unfortunately but hopefully my explanation makes it clear.

Comment: You should update your question to at least include all required data to get to an answer.  *The fourth column of matrix 2 is cut off*. How will this question help possible future lurkers for similar issue? Also it's advised to post data as data, not picture. Markdown table can be used. Also posting your actual formulas that failed helps.

Answer (score 1):

Apply formual `=SUMIF($G$2:$J$6,$L2,$B$2:$E$6)` on M2 and fill formula through the last row.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my issue was that my number of months (columns G through J) weren't rounded which is why my original formulas didn't work. I copied exactly what you had and kept getting 0 which made me realize. Thank you so much for your help!